# Symfony2 query builder does not return inner join data

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I using Symfony2 and Doctrine and I have this code in my repository.

`$cb = $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQueryBuilder("p")
                ->select($arrayColumns) //This array contains the fields
                ->from('MainBundle\Entity\Pedido', 'p')
                ->innerJoin('p.sucursal', 's');`

The $arrayColumns contains this: ['p.fecha', 's.descripcion', 'p.descripcion', 'p.id'].
When this query is executed, the result contains: ['p.fecha', 'p.descripcion', 'p.id']. It is omitting the 'sucursal' field.
The relation between Sucursal and Pedido is OneToMany.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should build your query in pure SQL and use RSM to map entities.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use:

```
$arrayColumns[] = "IDENTITY(p.sucursal)";
```

before the query

as described here: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/1955 and here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: It didn't work. It's rare, in other project this code worked good.